# Will this hash code change the URL location on randomize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

still practicing javascript.

Here is a JSBIN of a site that I have made that I can't seem to figure out how to make it so the URL will change once the video is clicked or randomized. 
(page load/refresh and click both trigger this)

http://jsbin.com/vesebu/1/edit?html,js,output

The page randomizes on load and page click with an array of videos. 
What I am trying to figure out is how to change the URL by appending an ID to the end of it. ie: mysite.com/6530  <-- last four digits representing the ID of the video. This will make the site shareable and is what I am trying to figure out how people are able to do this!

I have tried reading documentation on history.js, html5 pushstate as well as window.location hash and nothing seems to work.

```
M = function(d) {
        function a() {
            var a;
            a = window.location.hash;
            /^#\d+$/.test(a) && (window.location.href = "/" + a.slice(1));
            /^#!\d+$/.test(a) && (window.location.href = "/" + a.slice(2));
            f
        }
        y(a, d);
        return a
    }(n);
```

I was suggested this code by a friend but can't seem to make sense of it, especially with the jsbin I have. I'm completely lost here on how to do this, and have really tried reading up on it.

any help at all is definitely appreciated!

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

**Your hashes may be like this:**

```
#/2134/23423/
#2134/23423/
```

**result:**

```
windows.location = /2134/23423/;
```

then do something else.......

Hope it can help you ~

Comment: lose the quotes...sorry... '/1234/23423/'